# How to disable a spring factory registered via spring.factories by a dependency and keep this spring-boot dependency?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm facing an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28604) with a test execution listener registered by a dependency via an entry in `/META-INF/spring.factories`.

I'd still like to use this dependency - there are many goodies in it.

Is there a way to somehow suppress the invocation of the problematic (in my setup) listener?

Adding own `/META-INF/spring.factories` entry doesn't seem to overwrite, but rather extends the list of active listeners.

The listener in question is `org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener` from `spring-boot-test:2.5.6`.

Answer (score 0):

For `org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener` specifically, it's possible to filter out unwanted listeners by implementing a `DefaultTestExecutionListenersPostProcessor` and registering it itself as a `org.springframework.boot.test.context.DefaultTestExecutionListenersPostProcessor` in `META-INF/spring.factories`:

```java
public class SuppressMockitoResetMocksTestExecutionListener implements DefaultTestExecutionListenersPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<? extends TestExecutionListener>> postProcessDefaultTestExecutionListeners(Set<Class<? extends TestExecutionListener>> listeners) {
        return listeners.stream()
                .filter((listener) -> listener != org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.class)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

Kotlin example at https://github.com/mgurov/mockk-v-cached/commit/aea61ccd3afcf13a62736ce33391f0673640d446

via https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28604#issuecomment-968657072